# NSDateFormatter respect user settings - no minutes

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to turn a given hour to AM/PM or 24-hour display depending on the user's preferences.

I currently have:

```
+ (NSString *)formatWithTemplate:(NSString *)template {
    return [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:template options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
}

+ (NSString *)format:(NSDate *)date {
    [formatter setDateFormat:[MyFormatter formatWithTemplate:@"h a"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    return [formatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

Example usage:

`[MyFormatter format:24]` would display "24:00" if using a 24 hour clock but "12:00 PM" if using a 12 hour clock (in the user's device settings).

However, for 12 hour clock it keeps displaying: "12:00 PM". Is there any way to get rid of the :00 while respecting locale and the user's settings so that it displays: "12 PM" instead of "12:00 PM"?

When I use:

```
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
```

it respects the user's settings but completely ignores my format. However, if I use my format, it ignores the user's settings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would let the user settings prevail.  Then you've already got a method to get a string from that.  Then modify the string as necessary.

Since you're confident you only need to find and replace the string ':00' then do just that.  Here is something pretty simple:

```
NSString *string = @"12:00 PM"; //get this from the `dateFormatter` `format:date` method you have
NSString *newString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":00" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"newString %@",newString);
```